# Boost 12v battery cranking amps with supercaps

Tags: circuit-design, 12v

I have a setup where a 12V AGM battery is powering an inverter. This inverter, for brief periods (1 or 2 seconds - compressor starting) needs more amps than the battery can provide.

Is there a circuit that i can connect to the system that can briefly provide a quick boost in amps when they are needed? I was thinking along the lines of supercaps or a small high-amp battery?

I can't connect a similar battery in parallel just because there is not enough room for another big battery... I could do with a smaller one, but then we have the problem of charging/discharging batteries with different AH's in parallel.

So to elaborate on the specifics: 
Big battery of 100AH , inverter modified sine wave of 400watt, 800watt peak power, compressor of 70watt but no idea about the surge power.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since i'm not an expert in these things!

Comment: Without information about the current needed, the allowable voltage drop, and the exact duration of the "boost" it is difficult to give you a good answer...but I suspect that a supercapacitor is not going to be a practical solution.

Comment: Can you give us details (inverter model, or watt rating and surge watt rating, and battery rating in Ah?) I've never seen a setup where the inverter could handle a surge the battery couldn't, especially for just 1-2s. Typical AGM batteries have a 5-second surge rating that would be WAY beyond what the inverter could handle in typical use.

Comment: the problem is far more likely to be the inverter maxing out than the battery, which can dish out enough current to melt wires.

Comment: I've added some details in my post. I will continue testing today to zero out the culprit.

Comment: We need to know the minimum operating voltage of your inverter, as well as its efficiency at low loads.